# Javascript If Else Statement with mathFoor and mathRandom not working

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i am having some troubles with my code i am fairly new to this if anyone could assist me Thanks.

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 6;
var c = 7;
document.write(Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 5));

if (5) {
  alert("mission failed we will get them next time");
} else {
  alert("sorry");
}
```

Comment: What's the above code meant to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please start with learning documentation => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

```js
let RandomVal =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 5);
console.log(RandomVal);
if (RandomVal===5) {
  console.log("mission failed we will get them next time");
} else {
  console.log("sorry");
}
```